# From $|z-(1+i)|=1 $ to $ z-(1+i)=e^{it}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stucked on a Cauchy integral. My teacher made a transformation and I don't understand from where it comes.
\begin{align}
                               |z-(1+i)|&=1 \\
                               z-(1+i)&=e^{it}
\end{align}
I know that $e^{it} = \cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ according to Euler's formula.
So from where she obtained $e^{it}$? Thanks.

Comment: She obtained it from trigonometry...

Answer (score 2):

Every complex number of norm 1 can be written in the form $e^{it}$ for some real number, and can be written uniquely if we specify $t \in [0, 2\pi)$. You can see this geometrically, from the definition of the norm of a complex number and Euler's formula. Since the number $z - (1 + i)$ has norm 1 by your first line, it follows that there must be some real $t$ such that $$z - (1+i) = e^{it}.$$